# Announcing our newest(?) moderator

Tags: discussion, pro-tem-moderators

It is with pleasure that I announce the return of ColeValleyGirl to the team of Pro Temp Moderators at the Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange.

Some of you will know that ColeValleyGirl was first announced as a pro temp moderator on 17 Dec 2012, and was instrumental in helping the site establish and set its scope.

Unfortunately, ill health interrupted that stint of moderating in Aug 2014, which was not long after I became a pro temp moderator here.

Recently, in [What is the process for reinstating a moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336175/215590), a process by which former moderators could seek reinstatement was announced, and ColeValleyGirl has successfully taken that step, which I am sure will be to the great benefit of our site.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome -- I'm delighted to be back.